# Why is Poly1305, which is based on AES, faster than AES?

Tags: aes, performance, poly1305

The [web pages of BearSSL](https://www.bearssl.org/speed.html) have the following performance numbers:

- Poly1305 1730.92 MB/s, amd64, ctmulq
- AES-128 CTR 92.38 MB/s, amd64, ct64

It seems that constant-time Poly1305 is over an order of magnitude faster than AES-128 in the counter mode, without any special CPU instruction support in either.

My understanding is that Poly1305, however, is based on AES ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly1305)). Why can something based on AES be faster than AES by a so wide margin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Poly1305 is not **based** on AES, it was used **together** with AES in Bernstein's first description http://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf. For pseudocode of the Poly1305 algorithm see e.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.5.1.

GHASH is the 'hash function' in AES/GCM.

So if Poly1305 is faster than GHASH on some hardware this is no contradiction. And note that the peek values on your linked site are comparable: Poly1305 1730.92MB/s, GHASH 1740.96 MB/s.